# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Parameterized> to Class<? extends Runner>

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I am trying to execute the JUNIT tests with parameters.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class QtyByParam extends TestBase_Post {
```

I have included the jars `junit-4.11.jar`, `junit-dep-4.11.jar`

Is there anything missing? I am getting `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Parameterized> to Class<? extends Runner>` error at `@RunWith` section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong class imported:

```
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameterized;
```

this is the correct import:

```
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems your import is wrong. Change

```
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameterized;
```

to

```
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
```